# Any way to do filtering as well as summarizing in ddply?

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I'm just starting with`ddply` and finding it very useful. I want to summarize a data frame and also get rid of some rows in the final output based on whether the summarized column has a particular value. This is like `HAVING` as well as `GROUP BY` in SQL. Here's an example:

```
input = data.frame(id=     c( 1, 1, 2, 2, 3,   3),
                   metric= c(30,50,70,90,40,1050),
                   badness=c( 1, 5, 7, 3, 3,  99))
intermediateoutput = ddply(input, ~ id, summarize,
                           meanMetric=mean(metric),
                           maxBadness=max(badness))
intermediateoutput[intermediateoutput$maxBadness < 50,1:2]
```

This gives:

```
  id meanMetric
1  1         40
2  2         80
```

which is what I want, but can I do it in a single step within the `ddply` statement somehow?

Comment: If you're not already heavily committed to `plyr` then you might benefit from going directly to `dplyr` which is the new and improved version.

Comment: Just make sure you don't have them both loaded at the same time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try with `dplyr`. It is faster, and the code is much easier to read and understand, especially if you use pipes (`%>%`) :

```
input %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(meanMetric=mean(metric), maxBadness=max(badness)) %>%
    filter(maxBadness <50) %>%
    select(-maxBadness)
```

Following @Arun comment, you can simplify the code this way :

```
input %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(max(badness)<50) %>%
    summarize(meanMetric=mean(metric))
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent way in `dplyr` for `as.data.table(input)[, list(meanMetric=mean(metric)[max(badness) < 50]), by=id]`?

Comment: Yes you're right @Arun (as always !). The code can be simplified because you don't have to compute the `maxBadness` variable for filtering. Added it as an edit, I think this is more or less the equivalent of your `data.table` code.